# Можно ли в Oracle отменить сделанные изменения после Commit

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Вопрос теоретический, если в ходе сессии в базе данных Oracle я сделал транзакцию, например insert или update и сделал commit. Могу ли я вернуть все в первоначальное состояние, типа Undo или Rolback. Хочется узнать мнение специалистов по Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

советую прочитать статью про точки восстановления. Не ниже Oracle Database 10 g Release 2. Так же я на практике применял возможность восстановления через [Flashback Query](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashback_Query). Oracle дает возможность увидеть данные за некоторый период времени, обычно это последние 2 часа. Увидеть данные можно путём:

```
select * from (table name) as of timestamp (sysdate -60/1440)
```

т.е за последний час от текущей сессии.

Comment: Если даёте совет прочитать статью - давайте хотя бы ссылку на эту статью

Comment: Flashback Query этот инструмент нужно устанавливать или он уже в составе Оракла?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, по умолчанию он доступен, но глубина возможного возврата ограничена и на него нельзя полагаться. Если вам нужно гарантированное хранение данных из прошлого на заданную глубину времени, это настраивается отдельно вручную.

Comment: ОК спасибо, буду изучать. Главное что это можно, вопрос в точках сохранения и глубине во времени